# httpRequest and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, httprequest

I have a problem regarding excel VBA HTTP request and JavaScript. I want to do a search on an intranet site via "POST" but the submit button does seem to run a JavaScript to reload the site but I don't get how.

```
Public Function XmlHttpTutorial()

Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument

Dim myurl As String

myurl = "http://www.website.de"

xmlhttp.Open "POST", myurl, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0)1"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "serverTimeOffset=-3600149; browserTimeZone=-60;"

xmlhttp.Send ("var1=variable&var2=variable&var3=variable")


Debug.Print xmlhttp.responseText

End Function
```

This is the button itself

```
<input type="submit" name="button" tabindex="8" value="Find" onclick="closeWindow();uppercaseForm( this.form );" class="btn-small">
```

"closeWindow" just closes the window and "uppercaseForm" just puts all Input uppercase

and this is the Header

```
<form name="arrivalQueryForm" method="post" action="/opslink/arrivalQuery.do" onsubmit="setWindowId(this, 'windowId');">
```

the setWindowID only gets the window.name and replace brackets.

I have no idea how I get the right site back because nothing seems to work so far.

Answer (score 1):

The VBA has nothing to do with the HTML as far as I can tell. The XHR is baked in to the HTML form object (note that `method=post` attribute). That onsubmit is baked in with the HTML form.

I recommend you not use an HTML form element and hand script the XHR in JavaScript so you can see how the mechanism works via a `.click` event on a `button` element.

That VBA would be used if you wanted to fetch/XHR from within Excel itself without ever opening a web browser.

Comment: Thats what I try to fetch the data from withing Excel via XHR but I get a previous page which seems to do with the Javascript part of the website I try to reach.